# How to implement the "Member for " interval like SO in PHP?

Tags: php, relative-date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I calculate relative time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time)

It shows 2 days,2 month,1 year and so on.

How to do it?

Comment: Originally asked a (relatively) long time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen the code base but I assume it would be something like (pseudocode since I know as much about PHP as I do about the mating habits of white rhinos):

```
string duration (n): // days
    if n >= 365 return str(int(n/365)) + " years"
    if n >= 30 return str(int(n/30)) + " months"
    if n >= 7 return str(int(n/7)) + " weeks"
    return str(int(n)) + " days"
```

Adjust the value passed in and the denominators if you want a finer resolution than a single day (and allow for `"1 month"` instead of `"1 months"`) and you're good to go.

I wouldn't worry too much about the inaccuracies of the division (e.g., the average month has about 30.44 days) since it's only supposed to be an approximation.

Answer (score -1):

This is the PHP version of Pax pseudocode:

```
function duration ($n){
    if ($n > 365) return ($n/365)." years";
    if ($n > 30) return ($n/30)." months";
    if ($n > 7) return ($n/7)." weeks";
    return $n." days";
}
```

Comment: broken (e.g. missing $, moreover you forgot (int))...

Comment: you're right middus thanks, i have updated it already.